# Using both gradient clipping and learning rate warmup, should gradients be clipped during the warmup, or only once the warmup phase has completed?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training

I'm training a network using both learning rate warmup and an adaptive gradient clipping method outlined [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9231926). Is there a general consensus or anything in the literature relating to whether gradients should be clipped during the warmup phase or only after the warmup phase has completed.